# voltage dividers on inputs to current/power monitor ic

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-divider, high-voltage, pulse, power-measurement

I want to measure the current and voltage of exponential decay pulses delivered to resistive loads. The pulse peak voltages are between 20V and 400V and the time constants are between 1ms and 20ms. I am producing as many as 380 pulses, and each is spaced out by 50ms. Load resistances can be between 0.2kOhm and 5kOhm.

If I want to use a current/power monitor IC such as the INA219 (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina219.pdf?ts=1697522289890&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.findchips.com%252F), then I need to find a way to limit the voltage to the inputs of the INA219, which can only accept voltages between 0V and 26V. Other similar ICs have similar input voltage limits.

Is there any reason I should not add voltage dividers between the sensing resistor and the current/power monitor? Sometimes the load shorts, so the current/power monitor would need to be able to handle this. I am currently using an OPA350 with a voltage divider between the high side of the load and the OPA350. I have no issues measuring voltage and no issues when there is a short. I am looking to replace the OPA350 voltage measuring circuit with a solution for measuring voltage and current.

[image: current/power monitor with voltage dividers on the inputs]

I found this thread asking the same question but the question was not directly answered: https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/273209/extending-the-sensing-voltage-range-of-the-ina219.

I don't understand the circuit solution provided in the above thread.

---

Comment: no, the ina uses a differential amp for current, which would not work with a ground-referenced voltage divider. Put the INA low-side to avoid the high voltages (it will still do current just fine) and use whatever you got already for voltage readings.

Comment: i also don't think the INA219 is fast enough to catch all those pulses accurately.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I thought about low-side sensing, but I would still need to protect the INA219 inputs from short circuits, which happen every few thousand pulses or so.  Why don't you think the INA219 is fast enough?

Comment: 400v/200r=2a, which is in-range with a 0.1r shunt.  In terms of speed, I figure with the i2c report time, minimum sampling 12bit time,  and the gain roll-off above 1k, it might be difficult to discretely catch 1ms pulses. In practice, I am lucky to get 500 reports a second.

Comment: I see. I have been measuring voltage with 10 bit resolution at 10000 samples/second, which is high enough resolution for my needs. I was thinking I could run the INA219 at 10 bits as well and be just fine based on the ADC conversion time in the datasheet. However, if you are only getting 500 samples/second with 12 bit resolution then I think 10 bit for the INA219 is going to be too slow.